# Ansible jinja template using with_dict

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

So i'm still pretty new to Ansible, and i'm trying to generate a DHCP config file as my first real world Ansible project.

I'm using ansible 2.2.1.0 on RHEL7.

I'm coming unstuck as I have all of my config stored in yaml

```
---
dhcp_subnets:
  windows:
    description: "Windows Hosts"
    network: 10.33.7.0
    subnet: 255.255.255.0
    interface_name: eth0.152
    range_start: 10.33.7.32
    range_end:  10.33.7.250
    gateway:  10.33.7.254
    domain_name: "testlab.home"
    domain_name_servers:
      - 10.33.11.21
    ntp_servers:
      - 10.33.11.1
    hosts:
      152-rhevm:
        - description: "RHEV-M"
        - mac: "00:30:48:30:5B:1A"
        - address: "10.33.7.20"

  Linux:
    description: "Linux Hosts"
    network: 10.33.7.0
    subnet: 255.255.255.0
    interface_name: eth0.152
    range_start: 10.33.7.32
    range_end:  10.33.7.250
    gateway:  10.33.7.254
    domain_name: "testlab.home"
    domain_name_servers:
      - 10.33.11.21

    ntp_servers:
      - 10.33.11.1
    hosts:
      152-rhevm:
        - description: "RHEV-M"
        - mac: "00:30:48:30:5B:1A"
        - address: "10.33.7.20"
```

In the ansible playbook itself I can use the following code to print the attributes of each item

```
- debug:
  msg: "{{item.value.description}}"

with_dict: "{{ dhcp_subnets }}"

tags:
  - debug
```

However as i'm using this to generate a config file that contains these attributes, I have no idea how to do this. I can't see a with_dict option for jinja2.

I had hoped to use the template within a with_dict loop and have a template similar to the following

```
###############################################################
# DHCP client file - Managed by Ansible
###############################################################

ddns-update-style interim;
ignore client-updates;

{# Here I want to iterate over dhcp_subnets #}
subnet {{ item.value.network }} netmask {{ item.value.subnet }} {
    # {{ item.value.description }}

    interface "{{ item.value.interface_name }}";
    range               {{ item.value.range_start }} {{ item.value.range_end }};

        option subnet-mask              {{ item.value.subnet }};
        option routers                  {{ item.value.gateway }};

        option domain-name              "{{ item.value.domain_name }}";
        option domain-name-servers      {{ item.value.domain_name_servers }};
    option ntp-servers              {{ item.value.ntp_servers }};

}
```

Am I trying to solve this problem the wrong way ?

I've read some of the similar questions, but they seem to involve having to flatten out the dictionaries, and I'm keen to avoid that if possible.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over a dict in Jinja with this syntax:

```
{% for (key,value) in dhcp_subnets.iteritems() %}
    {{key}}={{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, would that mean I would have to iterate through every level of the dictionary ? or can I still us the the item.attribute notation ?

Comment: You should be able to use the item.attribute notation.  For example, the first pass through, `key` would be `windows` and `value` would be a dict containing `description`, `network`, `subnet`, etc.  So you could reference `value.subnet` instead of `item.value.subnet`

Comment: Thanks Scott, that's exactly what I was after.

Comment: Just one comment, as i'm using ansible 2.2 and python3 it's .items() not .iteritems()

Comment: @Jim the main issue with python's dictionaries is their order. 
you don't have any warranty about 2 separate runs of the for loop having the same order of keys.
IF you wish consistent content, you must use lists, otherwise you may lose idempotency or consistency.

And maybe if you're ok with alphanumeric sorting of keys, you can iterate over keys, and sort them.

Comment: like so:

```
{% for key in dhcp_subnets.keys() | sort %}
subnet {{dhcp_subnets[key].network}} netmask {{dhcp_subnets[key].subnet}} {
    # etc.
};
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be an old question but I had the same problem today.

On my case it does not work the `iteritems` as it needs to be imported.

An alternative way to solve this issue is:

```
{% for key,value in dhcp_subnets.items() %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

The official documentation from Ansible [no-dict-iteritems](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/testing/sanity/no-dict-iteritems.html)

Comment: right, it gave me `'dict object' has no attribute 'iteritems'`